# mybatis return primitive type for procedure call

Tags: java, mybatis

I want to return primitive type after call oracle procedure, 
here is my mybatis interface:

```
public interface ProcedureMapper {
    int getProcedureResult();
}
```

I want to execute a procedure or function then return status, I tried the config bellow:

```
<select id="getProcedureResult" statementType="CALLABLE" resultType="int">
        BEGIN   
           EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE temp_tt (id NUMBER(12) )';
           #{status,mode=OUT,jdbcType=INTEGER} := 0;
        EXCEPTION
           WHEN OTHERS THEN 
           #{status,mode=OUT,jdbcType=INTEGER} := -1;
        END;
</select>
```

doesn't work, will throw the Exception:

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Could not set property 'status' of 'class java.lang.Class' with value 'null' Cause: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no setter for property named 'status' in 'class java.lang.Class'
```

I know I can set resultType to Java Bean with 'status' property inside, but I just want to return primitive type not java bean, any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps this will work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903159/how-to-use-mybatis-to-return-a-value-from-procedure-call

Comment: There seems to be a discussion here http://mybatis-user.963551.n3.nabble.com/Stored-procedure-returning-integer-td2715317.html - but the result is not encouraging.

Comment: I can't find the solution from the url

Comment: As I said, it's just a discussion and the result seem to be that it's not possible if your procedure call doesn't actually return something but only writes OUT parameters.

Answer (score 0):

write your procedure like this in string -

```
public String proc = "BEGIN\n"
+"\tEXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE temp_tt (id NUMBER(12) )';\n"
+"\tstatus := 0;\n"
+"\tEXCEPTION\n"
+"\t\tWHEN OTHERS THEN\n" 
+"\tstatus := 0;\n"
+"\tEND;\n"
```

and  execute below statement in your java code insted where you are calling that procuder in mybatis

```
session.getConnection().prepareCall(String.format(proc)).execute();
```

ANOTHER SOLUTION IS:

another solution is **create a your procedure in database** and save it.
and call it from mybatis

```
<update id="getProcedureResult" statementType="CALLABLE">
    {call some_procedure(
     #{status, javaType=java.lang.Integer, jdbcType=INTEGER, mode=OUT})
    }
</update>
```

Comment: @fudy whats the reason? This should works.
but from the reference [link]  its good

link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548089/which-is-faster-statement-or-preparedstatement

Comment: Yes, I know it can work, but the code style is not good, take flexibility and maintainability into account, I prefer to configure the SQL in XML configuration file, that's why I choose Mybatis not raw JDBC.